# Invoking database using xquery giving duplicate values

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql, osb, xquery-update, xquery-3.0

I am using a XQuery to query database in an OSB project. Consider the
following table:

```
userId Name    Category
------ ------- --------
1      Dheepan Student
2      Raju    Student
```

and the XQuery

```
let $userName:=fn-bea:execute-sql(
            $dataSourceJndiName,
            xs:string("NAME"),
            xs:string("select NAME from USER where CATEGORY= 'Student'")
           )/*:NAME[1]
return <root> {data($userName)} </root>
```

For this query I am getting the result as `<root>Dheepan Raju</root>`. But I
need to return only one row even the query returns more than one row like the
following `<root>Dheepan</root>`. I have used predicate `[1]` in the query but
no clue why it concatenates the values and returning. Can anybody tell me how
to return only the first row when more than one row is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper paranthesis:

```
let $userName:=(fn-bea:execute-sql(
$dataSourceJndiName,
xs:string("NAME"),
xs:string("select NAME from USER where CATEGORY= 'Student'")
)/*:NAME)[1]
return <root> {data($userName)} </root>
```